# Installing Ubuntu 16 on a Cisco C240M3

Tags: ubuntu, installation, centos

I have been trying for a week to get Ubuntu to install on a Cisco c240M3 server and am out of ideas. It gets to the boot process and crashes with a Machine Check Exception/Kernel Panic.

[I made a video a put it on youtube](https://youtu.be/nXxP_WrDyMY)

I have googled more than you can imagine. This hardware is supposedly ["certified" to run Ubuntu](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201311-14358/), but I have tried just about every imaginable combination of Bios settings to try and get it to work. I have even removed all PCI riser cards (so, no Hypervisor or Disks) and it still happens.

The best I can get is if I add `clocksource=jiffies acpi=ht` ([based on this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1040026)) to the boot process, I have also tried `acpi=off`. It gets almost all the way through the install process and then suddenly reboots. 
It did have an old version of CentOs (6.2) on the HV when I started, but since I was able to get Ubuntu to install most of the way, that install is gone now since the installer formatted the disks of course. However, I was in poking around in that install prior to trying this and the boot options on that showed:

```
title CentOS
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.36.4 ro root=UUID=4d3a23b0-b162-4f02-af49-6dab4fa15d55 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet raid=noautodetect elevator=noop console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 acpi=ht rdloaddriver=md_mod
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.36.4.img
```

Comment: Did you run a memory test? And how much RAM have you got? (I can't find the amount of RAM in the [Ubuntu certification page](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201403-14834/) (while it reports the actual keyboard used...).

Comment: Mem test = yes. All hardware checks out. 384GB Ram. I'm still trying various things, and, I *think* this has something to do with the clock source. I guess Ubuntu uses `tsc`, but I have tried a myriad of other options, all to no avail. This server also allows installing the OS to a hypervisor (onboard 30GB disk), but even though it is call a "hypervisor", it's not actually a VM/KVM, etc. The idea being that you install the OS there and then all the disks (24x1TB SSD's) are all available for a raid 10 partition. Maybe it's some setting I need to change in the BIOS, but there are a *lot*.

Comment: After trying every OS under the sun (even Windows 10 and Windows Server...ugh), a [custom built VMWare ESXi](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?productId=491&downloadGroup=OEM-ESXI60U1B-CISCO) is the only thing that worked.